# Line break within arrow function throws “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `=>`”

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I’m getting the error *“Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `=>`”* on my console when I put the `e` parameter in parentheses and then use an ES6 arrow function. However, there’s no error when I remove the parameter from the parentheses. Should the parameter not have parentheses?

```js
document.querySelector("#book-form").addEventListener("submit", (e) 
=> {
  // …
});
```

Comment: Are you pasting into console with line-breaks as above?

Comment: This is probably interpreted as  `(e); => {` because of semicolon injection, so it's not valid arrow function.

Answer (score 3):

Arrow functions cannot have a newline between the parameters and the `=>`:

[14.2 Arrow Function Definitions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arrow-function-definitions)

> ArrowFunction[In, Yield, Await]:
>
> - ArrowParameters [?Yield, ?Await] **[no LineTerminator here]** => ConciseBody

Either remove the newline, or put it somewhere else. You could also use a named function instead, eg:

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
  // ...
};
document.querySelector("#book-form").addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function call and function declarations are not closed. Secondly, the arrow cannot be on its line alone.

```
//Event: add book
document.querySelector("#book-form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  //prevent default
  e.preventDefault();
  // get form value
  const title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
  const author = document.querySelector("#author").value;
  const isbn = document.querySelector("#isbn").value;
//Close function body, then function call.
});
```

Comment: which function call and function call declarations are not closed?

Comment: see the final line. The call to addEventListener was never closing, and your arrow function body was not closed